# Get the first document from every Elasticsearch route

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an Elasticsearch index with route key of day in the following format `"yyyyMMdd"`. Each day a lot of new documents are added. At the end of the month I would like to query if there are any days when for some reason a document haven't been added by a source. There is a `source_id` field representing the source.

I got it so far that I need to give all the routekeys, like `20160101`,`20160102` etc. and filter by the `source_id`. But this can return hundreds of thounsands of documents, I may need to paginate through them all.

Is there a way to only know if there is a routing key which doesn't have matching document with the given `source_id`, so essentially I would only return 31 documents or less to my application code, so it would be easy to iterate through and check if there is a day without document.

Any ideas?

Comment: are use using [routing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/routing-value.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Terms Aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the [`_routing`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-routing-field.html) field to know what all routing values have been used. See the query below:

```
POST <index>/<type>/_search
{
   "size": 0,
   "query": {
      "term": {
         "source_id": {
            "value": "VALUE" <-- Value of source_id to filter on
         }
      }
   },
   "aggs": {
      "routings": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "_routing",
            "size": 31  <-- We don't expect to get more than 31 unique _routing values
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Corresponding Nest code is as under:

```
var response = client.Search<object>(s => s
    .Index("<index name>")
    .Type("<type>")
    .Query(q => q
        .Term("source_id", "<source value>"))
    .Aggregations(a => a
        .Terms("routings", t => t
            .Field("_routing")
            .Size(31))));

var routings = response.Aggs.Terms("routings").Items.Select(b => b.Key);
```

`routings` will contain the list of routing values you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try it tomorrow. Do you have the NEST syntax for it by any chance?

Comment: It works, thank you! Special thanks for the Nest code!